# Explicit last function parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript 2.7.2 and later, is it possible to declare a function with dynamic parameters, with the last parameter being of an explicit/enforced type?

I'm trying to write an ambient TypeScript declaration for a JavaScript library that uses functions with dynamic parameters, while expecting the last parameter to always be a specific callback function.

Comment: `(...args: any[], lastArg: any)` ? You know, with actual types and whatnot.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This would give you `error TS1014: A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list.`

Comment: That's weird, I could've sworn I'd used it before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic solution is not possible. You need to declare as many overloads as you think are useful.

```
declare function foo(p1: any, cb: () => void): void;
declare function foo(p1: any, p2: any, cb: () => void): void;
declare function foo(p1: any, p2: any, p3: any, cb: () => void): void;
// ...
declare function foo(...args: any[]): void;
```

Comment: Was I foolishly hopeful that the latest TypeScript evolved from this stupidity? So much for a high-level scripting language :)

Comment: Well, it's not possible to have an additional named parameter after a rest parameter in JS either. I guess the TypeScript devs decided not to stray too far away from actual JS. There's a proposal for [variadic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), maybe it'd allow for a more elegant solution to your problem, if it ever lands. Something like `foo<...T>(...args: [...T, () => void])`.